# How to convert base64 image embedded in XML to UIImage?

Tags: ios, xml, swift, uiimage, base64

How can I convert the base64 data that is embedded in XML as shown in the screenshot below, to an UIImage?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to parse the XML. On iOS there is no `NSXML`, so you need to use the `NSXMLParser` instead, which is a primitive event-driven callback parser (opposed to a complex tree parser you could use in macOS).

So let's define some sample data:

```
let xmlString =
    "<base64Binary xmlns=\"TestTestTest\">"
    + "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAA0JCgsKCA0LCgsODg0PEyAVExIS"
    + "EyccHhcgLikxMC4pLSwzOko+MzZGNywtQFdBRkxOUlNSMj5aYVpQYEpRUk//"
    + "2wBDAQ4ODhMREyYVFSZPNS01T09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09P"
    + "T09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT0//wAARCABAABwDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QA"
    + "GgAAAgMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwUCBAYAAf/EACwQAAIBAwMCBAUFAAAAAAAA"
    + "AAECAwAEEQUSITFBBiJhcRMUUYGhFSNCkeH/xAAXAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    + "AAADAgQA/8QAHREAAgICAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECERIhAyIxMv/aAAwDAQAC"
    + "EQMRAD8AvWMQkSViFbaRkkZ4+g9aJeJbwMIljJmZN6ozEZHrQI5JYLOL4UbF"
    + "jJlwnHOKSyzXqssLi4AUnDMd+RnPLVlXZWy4RWKbGuzdOUjJQdSM5xRBa4/n"
    + "n3ryxKmzExBy/JzQpZiX8r4FZnJ3oAPO7LYwrErOXGSR0J/yluq6o1rGlogX"
    + "LKN8mOc0y0hwmlQNu3B5n69qz/iONWmYgg4PIBzitS8Rr49xLBl1aOHBMLBw"
    + "duDnaO3vRbdLiSFXlwWPeu0lhc2aI+d6DB+9WN6W5Ma9BRzlTxSAl6TMgt7a"
    + "3gbyg7nH0znmkGqXSSXDq7qiHqc9a0fiNYJLG1eNCFdyntwax8ypIyI0Y3gY"
    + "3Y6U1V6PD50PtIjYQtMysgY5QHrt7E1NkLOSS3Jplo8lvdaahuR+7H5HI4yR"
    + "0P3FW/k7N+cfmpfE27AknYqvJIv0KNpD543O30Oazb2N2WNwhBHOUzzj61qv"
    + "EdlKbyxt3SZkLbpBFFlQPccZ96OYkaN3RSSQdoaEDnHApFBl50kkIfD1yZpZ"
    + "o1cKAg3AnvmmLSOGI+J/RoPh6xayaVb3Tpd85DBgQdqjsefc0+e1swxAtM+u"
    + "7r+a7CTJm7Z//9k="
    + "</base64Binary>"
```

Now let's parse that. Therefor we need a primitive delegate, like this:

```
/// Extracts the content of the first <bas64Binary> tag in the XML
class Base64BinaryExtractor: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {

    private var active: Bool = false
    var base64String: String? = nil

    func parser (
            _ parser: XMLParser,
            didStartElement elementName: String,
            namespaceURI: String?,
            qualifiedName qName: String?,
            attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]
        )
    {
        // We must not have a string yet
        guard self.base64String == nil else {
            // If we do, this is a second <bas64Binary> tag or
            // it's a tag within a tag.  We ingore both.
            self.active = false
            return
        }
        // We only care for "<base64Binary>"
        guard elementName == "base64Binary" else { return }

        // Time to collect the string
        self.active = true
        self.base64String = ""
    }

    func parser (
            _ parser: XMLParser,
            didEndElement elementName: String,
            namespaceURI: String?,
            qualifiedName qName: String?
        )
    {
        // No matter what element, no matter if we were active,
        // we are not active anymore once any tag ends.
        self.active = false
    }


    func parser (
            _ parser: XMLParser,
            foundCharacters string: String
        )
    {
        // Ignore everything unless we are active
        guard self.active else { return }
        self.base64String!.append(string)
    }
}
```

The actual parsing then is just converting the string to data, setting up the parser, setting up the delegate and making it run:

```
let xmlData = xmlString.data(using: .utf8)
// TODO: Check xmlData being nil and handle that!
let parser = XMLParser(data: xmlData!)

let delegate = Base64BinaryExtractor()
parser.delegate = delegate

let parseOK = parser.parse()
// TODO: Check parseOK and handle if not!
// TODO: Check delegate.base64String being nil and handle!
```

Now all you need to do is decoding the base64 to raw data and make an image out of it:

```
let rawData = Data(base64Encoded: delegate.base64String!)
// TODO:  Check raw data being nil (bad base64!) and hanlde that!

let image = UIImage(data: rawData!)
```

The code above assumes that `rawData` contains data of an image format known to iOS (e.g. PNG, JPEG, TIFF) If this is not the case, you need to convert the format, maybe using an external image library to process it.

And as a bonus, here are two valuable tips for future questions on StackOverflow:

1. Always provide sample data. A screenshot doesn't cut it as I cannot use it for testing sample code. Sample data helps people a lot that try to help you, so you will get more answers, better answers and you will get them quicker if you provide sample data.
2. Break complex problems into smaller sub-problems and then ask *one question per sub-problem*, instead of creating complex "covers it all" questions, this increases your chances for fast and accurate replies dramatically. It's also how you should develop software: Divide and Conquer. Convert large problems into small sub-problems, solve one sub-problem at a time, if you've solved them all, then you've solved the complex problem as a whole, too. E.g. this problem can be broken down into three sub-problems:

   1. Parsing an XML document to extract content of a specific tag
   2. Converting base64 data to raw data
   3. Creating an image from raw data